# Custom shapes on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, xlsx

I need to create some battle maps and wonder if there is any way to create custom predefined shapes using google tools (https://www.google.com/maps/d) without JS coding similar to the ones from these links (may be using KML or any other Google format):
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Map_Battle_of_Stalingrad-ru.svg

And if the only way is coding JS, can you please give some hints whats the best way to create similar "flexable" shapes that can you put on google map without coding each coordinate, but create a template that can be used, to resize, rotate, bend the shape on the map.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that much experience with this (I did a similar thing once at a co-op using the KML layer at https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zJFboT3y3LYI.khNwbNHyFmws&msa=0)

That said, you should be able to draw on the google maps from the link you provided, creating all the layers and it will allow you to export it to KML from there. It may be a lot of work to draw the shapes, but it will certainly be easier than typing in the coordinates.